# ajax response not loading div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form validation class that returns an error array.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/oop/register.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
        var emptyDiv= $('<div></div>');

        jQuery.each(response, function(i, val){
            emptyDiv.clone().insertAfter('ul#state-list li:nth-child(' + val + ')');
        });
        $('#signupalert').append(emptyDiv);
        $('#signupalert').fadeIn('slow');
}});
```

The alert shows the response is an array of errors but in the console i get the following error:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '209' in Array
(
    [0] => username is required
    [1] => first_name is required
    [2] => last_name is required
    [3] => password is required
    [4] => confirm_password is required
 ...<omitted>...)
```

Comment: Show us how you return the array.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use normal `for` instead of `jQuery.each` maybe the returned response is not javascript array object

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/oop/register.php",
data: data,
success: function(response){
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    alert(response);
    var emptyDiv= $('<div></div>');

    for(var x = 0; x < response.length; x++) {
       emptyDiv.clone().insertAfter('ul#state-list li:nth-child(' + response[x] + ')')
    }
    $('#signupalert').append(emptyDiv);
    $('#signupalert').fadeIn('slow');
}});
```

Also to make sure that `response[x]` is the string value which you are looking for try alert it; or you can also check the real value of response in Dev mode of your browser or if you have some tools like Fiddler use that one, just to make sure the response value is either a normal array or an array object

Comment: I guess you are returning a JSON object instead of and array or object. In this case use `$.parseJSON(response)` to convert the scripted JSON to a JSON array. I modified my solution, hopefully this will work